# Rails with JQuery fileupload gives expected Array (got Rack::Utils::KeySpaceConstrainedParams

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, file-upload, rack

I'm preforming an ajax file upload in Rails with jQuery fileupload. The first upload works fine, but when I try a consecutive upload I get a server error saying:

```
 Unexpected error while processing request: expected Array (gotRack::Utils::KeySpaceConstrainedParams) for param `photos'
/home/uriklar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/utils.rb:114:in `normalize_params'
```

This is how my upload process is working:
In an Apartment form I have a nested form for photos

```
= f.simple_fields_for Photo.new do |photo|
  = photo.file_field :photo, label: false, class: 'photo_upload_input', multiple: true, name: "photos[]", data: {url: '/apartments/'+@apartment.id.to_s+'/photos/new'}
```

and in my javascript:

```
$('.photo_upload_input').fileupload();
```

The first file upload sends me to the correct action (Photos#update) and saves the photos correctly. It even works for multiple files.. It calls the action separately for each file.

```
    def update
     @apartment = Apartment.find(params[:apartment_id])
     @photo = @apartment.photos.create(photo: params[:photos][0])
   end
```

The problem is, when I try to upload a second round of photos I get the error written above. It doesn't even hit the controller... 
What does this error mean? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

After digging deep inside the Rack code and understanding very little of it, I decided to do change:
`name = "photos[]"` to `name="photos"` (in the file_field input) and now it's all working!
Not really sure why... but that's my solution